# In FSMs does one State last one clock cycle or more?

Tags: cpu-architecture, state-machine, fsm

Need to design a simple one for school. 
More specifically a Moore FSM. Im not sure how state transitions happen, is it next state each clock?
I need to know because im wondering if i can shift a register and add a value to it, all in the same state... Could use wave edges?

**EDIT**:

I have to design the **ALU** part with registers as a schematic from gate-level, so no target **CPU**.

I made the algorith diagram, then put states to function blocks according **Moore FSM** rules. each block of operations gets one state.

For instance in a state ***S1***, i have the following operations: ***y0 = shift Reg1 left; y1 = Reg1 = Reg1 + Reg2***. So the microcommand that the control part of Moore **FSM** outputs would be ***0000011 (yn...y1,y0).*** this microcommand should be the input to the ALU part which i need to design. Now i realized **y1,y0** will conflict eachother, since both are using **Reg1.**

Its problematic since I dont actually have the Control part, I have to imagine the core FSM and design only the ALU with registers. This is why i was wondering if i get more than one clock cycle, so i can sequence **y0,y1** or do i have to complete the entire operation in one clock?

I plan on making parallel-in, parallel-out non-shift registers, obviously i cant do the two operations of the microcommand at the same time. So what can i do:

```
1. make extra states? which i really dont want to do
2.use edges of a single clock? (might cause problems?)
3.Assume i get a preset amount of ticks from the clock to complete the microcommand ?
This would make the most sense, but i dont know if its the case.
The control unit does "know" the algorithm and thus how many operations need to be performed
```

I have to note again, that the control part is totally abstract and i have no idea how this is handled in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) itself has no inherent notion of time (although it can be defined). A [Moore machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) is simplified model and lacks the ability to even formally represent an ever progressing "time" (without, of course, implementing the counting entirely with states); remember, there is only a *finite* set of states.

In any case, time can be introduced in an *implementation* detail of a particular FSM and the amount of time might required to change between particular states might not be constant. (A particular FSM might also map differently to different *implementations*.) In the case of a [clocked system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clocked_sequential_system) it would require looking into how each "clock" is defined in the *implementation*; it might be leading edge, trailing edge, both, or something entirely different.

Instead of looking at the FSM here for guidance (it is just the logical progression of states), look at the opcodes (or whatever the implementation is) that the FSM represents, and how the CPU (or whatever the implementation is) in question "executes" them.

(What do the books say? ;-)

Comment: I explained the situation a bit more in my edit. (studyign IT at uni, What books ;p?) Do you think the 3rd assumption is something i could make?

Comment: @Ollosaurusrex I have no idea :) Talk to classmates/TA/teacher for guidance. One thing I have learned though, is *explicitly state* [new] assumptions and back them up with justifications. Even if wrong it provides a start for understanding and documents the choices made.